# Как собирать и внедрять семантику на сайт после прошлого специалиста?

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы, поисковая-оптимизация, google-search

Есть сайт, прошлый специалист не собрал семантику.
Придется собирать новую семантику.

Но как узнать, какие запросы были внедрены?
Как вообще собирать семантику, не зная семантику текущего сайта?

Я новичок в СЕО, буду рад вашим ответам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Соберите семантическое ядро и подготовьте наиболее подходящие страницы для групп фраз.
Затем начинайте оптимизировать страницы и при этом обращайте внимание на уже существующий трафик из поиска чтобы не сломать уже достигнутые результаты.